# Set parameter for api url in Angular 6 service

Tags: angular

I have a get request that requires passing some data, how do I do that in my service:

```
private campaignUrl = environment.apiUrl + '/campaign/';

    constructor(private http: HttpRequestService) { }

    getCampaign(uuid) {
        return this.http.post(this.campaignUrl);
    }
```

I need to pass the id after campaignUrl, and this is my api url in swagger:

> /api/campaign/{uuid}/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is adequate, but I'll offer this since you were *almost there* with your example, using [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (back-ticks):

```
private campaignUrl = environment.apiUrl + '/campaign/';

constructor(private http: HttpRequestService) { }

getCampaign(uuid) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.campaignUrl}/${encodeURI(uuid)}`);
}
```

Or with arrows

```
getCampaign = (uuid) => this.http.get(`${this.campaignUrl}/${encodeURI(uuid)}`);
```

Note that you probably want to call [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) (since Angular won't do that for you). You could skip this if you can *guarantee* that the string passed to `getCampaign` is *always* a uuid format (`nnnn-nnnn-...`).

Also, you say "get request" in your question but call `.post`, so I assumed your text was correct and code was not.

Comment: Yep, that's a better way to concatenate string. You're right.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Your answer is just fine and maintains the original style of the question. I only added this "for completeness".

Answer (score 3):

Is a get or is a post?

anyway you can do it this way :

```
return this.http.post(this.campaignUrl + uuid);
```